# How to find out whether the pop up is visible (shown on existing screen)?

Tags: qt, qml

I have a popup in my app which can be moved by the user to another screen. The popup is show in intervals. When the user unplug or turn off the screen and the popup is shown, actually it is not, because the screen is off. How to detect when the popup (Qt quick Window type widget) is really visible for the user?

Comment: I would imagine some amount of the information in the Screen attached object would change to let you detect that case. For more info: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-screen.html

Comment: I was thinking the same, but I have not find the solution the screen object. Maybe is there and I am not so skillful to see it.

Comment: I'm guessing you'll need to use C++ and hook to the QGUIApplication::screenRemoved signal to check if the Screen attached object is still present in QGUIApplication::screens.